# python: read keyboard input while loop without stopping the process?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently working on a personal project (I don't know python that well) that prints content from a database in the console.

```
import readchar

while True: #loop that checks for keyboard input
    if repr(readchar.readkey()) == "'t'": #listens whether t pressed
        if expose: #expose certain data that was shown as *****
            expose = False
        else:
            expose = True
    addlist('Data', 'DE', 'Data212', 'Email', 'Random data') # Adds data to sqlite db and 
prints it
    sleep(1)
```

My problem is that when I use **readchar** the loop stops until a key is pressed, I tried using the **keyboard** library but then I had to spam the key several times until it was recognized?
Maybe there is a simple method, but I was not able to solve it, please help me

Comment: Easiest way to spawn another thread that will wait for input, you can also use the `select` and `curses` modules but they are hard to get to work cross-platform.

Comment: To add to what @mousetail said, the python library you would probably use for multithreading is multiprocessing: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html